# XML deserialization - throwing custom errors

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

So I have the following method:

```
private int? myIntField
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public int? IntField{
    get {
        return this.myIntField;
    }
    set {
        this.myIntField= value;
    }
 }
```

Now, I am deserializing xml from a post, if for whatever reason I am getting a string, such as "here is the int field: 55444" instead of 55444, the error I get in response is: `Input string was not in a correct format.` which isn't very specific, especially considering I will have more than one int field I need to verify.

Originally, I was planning something like this:

```
private string myIntField
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public int? IntField{
    get {
        return this.myIntField.CheckValue();
    }
    set {
        this.myIntField= value;
    }
 }
```

Where CheckValue performs a `try-parse` to an Int32, and if it fails it returns a null and adds an error to a list. However, I can't seem to nail this set-up for the generated classes.

Is there I way I can throw a specific error if I am getting strings in place of ints, DateTimes, etc?

Comment: You should only use deserialization on data that were created by serialization. In other cases, especially when you have to handle possible errors, you should just parse the input regularly (e.g. using LINQ to XML, XPath, etc.)

Comment: @Tonnie: The approach you suggest seems like a valid one.  What do you mean by 'I can't seem to nail this set-up for the generated classes'.

Comment: @Tonnie: also what do you mean by 'post'.  An HTTP POST, or a blog post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Input string was not in a correct format" messages comes from a standard `System.FormatException` raised by a call to `int.Parse`, added to the automatically generated assembly that does the deserialization. I don't think you can add some custom logic to that.

One solution is to do something like this:

```
    [XmlElement("IntField")]
    [Browsable(false)] // not displayed in grids
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)] // not displayed by intellisense
    public string IntFieldString
    {
        get
        {
            return DoSomeConvert(IntField);
        }
        set
        {
            IntField = DoSomeOtherConvert(value);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int? IntField { get; set; }
```

It's not perfect, because you can still get access to the public `IntFieldString`, but at least, the "real" `IntField` property is used only programmatically, but not by the XmlSerializer (`XmlIgnore`), while the field that's holding the value back & forth is hidden from programmers (`EditorBrowsable`), grids (`Browsable`), etc... but not from the `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy if you have schema(s) for you XML and validate it against schema before deserializing. Suppose you have schema(s) for your XML, you can initialize a XmlSchemaSet, add your schema(s) in it and the:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(xml); // this a string holding the XML
document.Schemas.XmlResolver = null; //if you don't need to resolve every references
document.Schemas.Add(SchemaSet); // System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet instance filled with schemas
document.Validate((sender, args) => { ... }); //args are of type ValidationEventArgs and hold problem if there is one...
```

Personally I think this is a better approach, because you can validate your XML before deserializing and be sure the XML is correct otherwise the deserializer will most probably throw an exception if something is wrong and you will almost never be able to show a meaningful feedback to the user...
P.S. I recommend creating schema(s) describing the XML

Answer (score 2):

I have three approaches for you.

- Assuming your data is being entered by a user in a user interface, use input validation to ensure the data is valid.  It seems odd to allow random strings to be entered when it should be an integer.
- Use exactly the approach you suggest above.  Here's an example using LINQ Pad

  ```
  void Main()
  {
      using(var stream = new StringReader(
                "<Items><Item><IntValue>1</IntValue></Item></Items>"))
      {
          var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Container));

          var items = (Container)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

          items.Dump();
      }
  }

  [XmlRoot("Items")]
  public class Container
  {
      [XmlElement("Item")]
      public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
  }

  public class Item
  {
      [XmlElement("IntValue")]
      public string _IntValue{get;set;}

      [XmlIgnore]
      public int IntValue
      {
          get
          {
              // TODO: check and throw appropriate exception
              return Int32.Parse(_IntValue);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Take control of serialization using IXmlSerializable, here's another example

  ```
  void Main()
  {
      using(var stream = new StringReader(
                "<Items><Item><IntValue>1</IntValue></Item></Items>"))
      {
          var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Container));

          var items = (Container)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

          items.Dump();
      }
  }

  [XmlRoot("Items")]
  public class Container
  {
      [XmlElement("Item")]
      public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
  }

  public class Item : IXmlSerializable
  {
      public int IntValue{get;set;}

      public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
      {
          writer.WriteElementString("IntValue", IntValue.ToString());
      }

      public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
      {
          var v = reader.ReadElementString();
          // TODO: check and throw appropriate exception
          IntValue = int.Parse(v);
      }

      public XmlSchema GetSchema()
      {
          return(null);
      }
  }
  ```